# Is it possible to get a chain burnt of processors/mb?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure

The problem is as follows: I just got my dad's computer and have (had) a bunch of MBs, AM2 processor standing out.

His AGP slot had some problems and the computer refused to start with a video card other than the on-board card.

1 week before:

- MB1 - processor 1 - power 2 => perfectly working
- MB2 - processor 3 - power 3 => perfectly working
- MB3 - processor 3 - power 2/3 => perfectly working

Replaced his MB with a mb of mine (MB1), but left his power supply (which to be honest, apart from the 24-pin connector had another one with 4 pins connected to his MB) and tried it.... The results are as follows.

MB 1:

- processor 1 - power 1 => smells burnt and make annoying sound (possibly mb voltage regulators)
- processor 2 - power 1 => same
- processor 2 - power 2 => same

Replaced MB1 with another MB of mine.

MB 2:

- processor 2 - power 3 => smells burnt and runs for a couple of seconds
- processor 3 - power 3 => smells burnt
- processor 2 - power 2 => same
- processor 4 - power 2 => smells burnt instantly

And finally changed everything except the power 2 (which was perfectly ok 1 week before)

MB 3:

- processor 4 - power 2 => smells burnt

Is it possible that power 1 burnt MB 1 which in turn burnt processor 2 and power 2 which in turn burnt MB 2 and 4 and processor 4?

I know it sounds crazy, but is it possible to get them burnt in chain???

I'm very curious what I got wrong, because I now have 4 MB, 4 CPU, and 2 PSU apparently broken, and I don't want to burn the last ones.

Comment: Are you sure that the surface you are using isn't conductive? You can test power supplies without having to have a motherboard attached, google for more info (it usually involves attaching a hard drive for some baseline load and bridging two pins on the ATX plug).

Comment: I'm testing on the carpet

Comment: Carpet = static electricity = fried components.  I would at this point put everything down and solicit the services of a professional.

Comment: It's hairless carpet... It can't generate any...

Comment: Does your mainboard has some configuration jumpers for cpu bus ratio and stuff like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a motherboard has faulty power circuitry, it can very well burn several processors. Processors burning motherboard? Sounds very unlikely.

Start by testing the power supplies independently: "To test the basic function of an ATX power supply, short the Green wire with one of the grounds. This should turn the power supply on." http://wiki.xtronics.com/index.php/ATX_Pinout#Testing_ATX_power_supplies

When doing this, put some load, like a fan or hard drive, to the power supply just to be on the safe side.